# Why does polar solvents favor Ketonization and non-polar solvents favor Enolization?

Tags: organic-chemistry, isomers, tautomer

I was just studying isomerism, when I came across this statement for keto-enol tautomerism:

> A polar solvent favors ketonization, while a non-polar solvent favors enolization.

And I just can't get my head around that why is it so.
**Can someone explain the mechanism by which polar solvents favor keto product formation?**

*PS: I also found this statement in the same text. I don't know if this would help in understanding the above question:*

> *Polar solvents are known to stablize anions by solvating the negative charge.*

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/83824/135348